# Implementing the same method signature from two 'interfaces'

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions, overriding

Using pure virtual methods for faux-interfaces in C++, what happens when a concrete class derives from two 'interfaces' which have an identical method declaration? e.g `X` sub-classes `Iaaa` and `Ibbb` and implements a method `virtual void setVisible(bool);`.

Does the fact `Iaaa` and `Ibbb` have no method body make things easier/better than a more classical diamond inheritance scenario, and lets `X::setVisible` *be* the implementation for both `Iaaa::setVisible` and `Ibbb::setVisible`?

I suppose a more C++ way of phrasing the question is *"what happens when one class uses MI to derive from 2 classes which have identical signatures for a pure virtual method".*

Comment: Did you try it? What is the behavior you see?

Comment: "_Does the fact Iaaa and Ibbb have no method body make things easier/better_" It never does. Why would it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> what happens when one class uses MI to derive from 2 classes which
>   have identical signatures for a pure virtual method

The behavior is well defined. The derived class overriding method will constitute implementation of both the interfaces (i.e. abstract `class`es with all pure `virtual` functions) methods.

Also, 2 other points from your question

1. diamond inheritance hasn't yet took place, because you haven't
   mentioned any common base for `Iaaa` and `Ibbb`
2. You cannot implement, 2 `X::setVisible(bool)` with same signature

Comment: "well defined" is the answer I was after - it sounds like there is no problem here.

Answer (score 10):

It depends.  If both functions have the same signature, and you want to
replace both of them with the same function, then just do it; there is
no problem, and your function will implement both of them.  If they have
different signatures, then you'll need two different functions to
implement them.  And if you want different implementations (likely the
case if the interfaces are unrelated), but they have the same signature,
then you'll need to introduce intermediate classes to "rename" them, 
e.g.:

```
class MaskSetVisibleInAaa : public Aaa
{
    virtual void setVisibleInAaa( bool ) = 0;
    virtual void setVisible( bool newStatus )
    {
        setVisibleInAaa( newStatus );
    }
};

class MaskSetVisibleInBbb : public Bbb
{
    virtual void setVisibleInBbb( bool ) = 0;
    virtual void setVisible( bool newStatus )
    {
        setVisibleInBbb( newStatus );
    }
};

class ConcreteImplementation
    : public MaskSetVisibleInAaa
    , public MaskSetVisibleInBbb
{
    virtual void setVisibleInAaa( bool );
    virtual void setVisibleInBbb( bool );
};
```

(I would also question your use of "faux-interface".  C++ fully supports
real interfaces—more so, in fact, than some other languages which
have an `interface` keyword.  An interface defines a contract; which,
unless the language has special support for programming by contract,
implies in most cases concrete code in the interface, with virtual
functions being private.)

Comment: a)I use "faux-interface" because interfaces are not a language construct in C++... not meaning to imply they aren't 'real' interfaces. An issue of technicality/nonclementure.... b)I this case I _would_ want the same implementation for both. But it _is_ worth mentioning.